# Is their SDK library to create Github Bot in python

Tags: python-3.x, github, botframework, github-api, github-app

I was moving towards creating Bot(Github App). I googled a lot but could not find it.
Is their any SDK, library to create Github bots in python as Slack-bolt, slack SDK for python to listen for web events?
There is [probot](https://github.com/probot/probot) which is for Node Development. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this conversation happened [here](https://github.com/probot/probot/issues/401), and the consensus was to use [this](https://github.com/flyingdice/probot-py) though it's not official GitHub, and looks under active development as of Feb 2022.

Answer (score -1):

This repository contains code for the Python version of the Microsoft Bot Framework SDK, which is part of the Microsoft Bot Framework

```
https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-python
```

Comment: Question is for Github Bot , not the microsoft